# If I have the primary key id do I need an AND clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I've been tasked with optimizing our SQL calls.
I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id = ? AND owner_id = ?
```

id is the **PK**

owner_id is an **Index** and a **FK**

Since I already have the id. Do I need the `AND owner_id = ?` clause?  Will it slow the query down if I do use it?

Comment: It depends on your requirements what filter conditions are required.

Comment: If the value of `owner_id` matters then you may not be getting the same result when you omit it, thus you'd be getting wrong data slightly faster. If it doesn't matter you should remove it for the sake of code maintainability.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález since the PK is unique it should only return one record.  Thus, you are correct, providing the owner_id should either return 1 or 0 records. It's a very small integrity test.  The passed in id should be owned by the passed in owner_id Post it as an answer and I'll choose you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.  But it offers no advantage.  I would expect even MySQL's optimizer to be smart enough to use the primary key index in this case.

However, if it did accidentally use the foreign key index, you probably wouldn't notice the difference in performance.

It does add a very, very, very small amount of overhead for the second comparison.  But that may not be measurable.